# jQuery - use link for show/hide function, but prevent link from opening in url

Tags: jquery

I've got a good jQuery show/hide function working; the problem is that if the link is opened by typing the URL directly, it doesn't degrade well--you can see all of the elements at once.

Is there any way to use the links in the show/hide function, but prevent the links from opening when typed directly into the browser address bar?

Here's my code:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav li a').first().addClass('blue');

    $('#nav li a').click(function(){

    $('#nav li a').first().removeClass('blue');
    $('#nav li a').removeClass('blue');
    $(this).addClass('blue');

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+'#content';  
    $('#content').hide(0,loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();  
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
    //window.location.hash = //$(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-0);  
    function loadContent() {  
        $('#conent').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $('#content').show(0,hideLoader());  
    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
    }  
    return false;  
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftcol">

<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="/option1">Option 1</a></li><br />
<li><a href="/option2">Option 2</a></li><br />
<li><a href="/option3">Option 3</a></li><br />
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the link's `href` isn't a URL you should probably use `#option1`

You could use the `hashchange` event to call a show/hide function?

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    showHideFunction(window.location.hash);
});
```

When you click a link the hash will change and the function is called.

If someone types in the address `http://domain.com/#option1`
Then you can grab the hash like this in your onload function.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash) {
    showHideFunction(hash);
}
```